# Erro com relacionamento - Laravel

Tags: laravel, query

Galera, estou com 2 tabelas relacionadas e quero mostrar 1 dado que tem uma apenas "puxando" esta relacao.

tabelas:

Users:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Permissions:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Table que vai listar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
@foreach(App\User::all() as $user)
                              <tr>
                                <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
                                <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
                                <td>{{$user->permission->name}}</td>
                                <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
                              </tr>
                              @endforeach
```

Model "User":

```
public function permission()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Permission', 'id', 'role');
}
```

erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é a chave estrangeira da permissão? O id ou name?

Comment: id é a chave de permissao, porem quero q mostre o name

Comment: O name é da user?

Comment: o name é do permission que eu quero que aparece, porem tambem name na User

Comment: Pode ver no anexo que coloquei na questão

Comment: Tenta colocar assim: `{{ $user->permission->name }}`

Comment: deu erro, colocarei na publicacao

Comment: Os dois usuários tem role cadastrados para ele? você pode tentar englobar em um método optional, por exemplo `{{ optional($user->permission)->name }}` caso o usuário não tenha relação com permission, retornará vazio

Comment: sim, cada um tem seu role cadastrado

Comment: Dá um var_dump no resultado do user

Comment: Tenta assim `{{ $user->permission[0]->name }`

Comment: Não faz isso acima, é gambiarra. Sinto muito, mas é. Tem o certo.

Comment: Como está no controler?

Comment: nao foi nenhum dos jeito

Comment: o controller não esta com nenhuma funcao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O segundo termo da função **belongsTo()** é o nome da chave tem que na tabela `users` que servirá de comparação com a tabela `permissions.`

```
public function permission()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Permission', 'role');
}
```

Automaticamente ele irá comparar com a coluna `id` da tabela `permissions`, a não ser que você defina no terceiro termo qual coluna deverá servir de comparação.

Comment: Apareceu a tabela, porem a coluna permissão sem dado.

Comment: Você alterou alguma coisa na sua view?

Comment: Eu troquei a função para `belongsTo()`.